# Select element from jQuery object with matching name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I've got a jQuery object that contains input fields like so:

```
var $inputs = $("#signup input");
```

Is there a way I can directly select one out of it where the name attribute equals a given value?

I've tried `$inputs.find("name=firstName").select();`, but it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use attribute-value selector here:

```
$("#signup input[name=firstName]");
```

**update:**

```
$inputs.filter("[name=firstname]");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xusqqweg/)**

Comment: I would like to find it in the `$inputs` object if that's possible.

Comment: Then where is the `$inputs` variable being used in your code?

Comment: I don't think that's right, either. You're only selecting the outer element of the object *if* it has the correct name attribute.

Comment: @isherwood: well that is what he wants.

Comment: No, we're looking for elements *inside* the object.

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

```
$inputs.filter("[name=firstName]").select();
```

Or, using my preferred syntax...

```
$inputs.filter('[name="firstName"]').select();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1w7kmobd/2)

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I've tried those, and the input is still not being selected. I don't think it finds it in the `$inputs`.

Comment: Hmm, in your fiddle your `$inputs` var contains the whole form object  and not only the inputs.

Comment: Answer updated with `filter()` instead of `find()` to include top-level elements. Milind had it more correct initially than I did.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$inputs.filter('[name="firstName"]');
```

**Special Note:**

`.select()` is used to select the text in the `input` but not to select the way you mean.

Comment: It does select it in the way I mean. :P

Comment: It selects the text of it, which was my intention.

Comment: Then I guess I read my own meaning into **Is there a way I can directly** ***select*** **one out of it where the name attribute equals a given value?**. My bad! Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $inputs = $("#signup");
$("[name=firstName]", $inputs).select();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/571ckuu0/